# Flutter + Firebase Messaging: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Object' in type cast

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to set up notifications in my flutter android application.

My setup looks like this:

main.dart:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Initialize Firebase
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  // Create FirebaseMessagingService instance
  FirebaseMessagingService firebaseMessagingService =
      FirebaseMessagingService.instance;

  try {
    // Request permission for receiving notifications
    final notificationSettings =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(provisional: true);

    // Listen for token refresh and save the token
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen((fcmToken) async {
      print('Firebase token: $fcmToken');
      await firebaseMessagingService.saveToken(fcmToken ?? '');
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error initializing Firebase: $e');
  }

  // Retrieve the current FCM token
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((String? token) async {
    if (token != null) {
      // Token retrieval successful, handle the token here
      print('FCM Token: $token');
      await firebaseMessagingService.saveToken(token);
      // You can send this token to your server or use it for other purposes
    } else {
      // Token retrieval failed
      print('Failed to retrieve FCM Token.');
    }
  }).catchError((error) {
    // Error occurred while retrieving the token
    print('Error retrieving FCM Token: $error');
  });

...
```

firebase_messaging_service.dart:

```
class FirebaseMessagingService {
  static final FirebaseMessagingService _instance =
      FirebaseMessagingService._internal();
  FlutterSecureStorage storage;

  FirebaseMessagingService._internal() : storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

// Getter method to access the singleton instance
  static FirebaseMessagingService get instance => _instance;

  String? FCMToken;

  factory FirebaseMessagingService() => _instance;

  Future<void> saveToken(String token) async {
    await storage.write(key: 'fcm_token', value: token);

    FCMToken = token;
  }

  Future<String?> readToken() async {
    String? token = await storage.read(key: 'fcm_token');

    FCMToken = token;

    return token;
  }

  Future<void> clearToken() async {
    await storage.delete(key: 'fcm_token');

    FCMToken = null;
  }

  // Send FCM message
  Future<void> sendFCMNotification(
      String token, String title, String body) async {
    FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    try {
      print("_firebaseMessaging: ${_firebaseMessaging}");
      await _firebaseMessaging.sendMessage(
        to: token,
        data: {
          'title': title ?? '',
          'body': body ?? '',
        },
      );
      print('FCM notification sent successfully.');
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      // Handle the error

      print('Error sending FCM notification: $e');
      print('StackTrace: $stackTrace');
    }
  }
}
```

my page where I try to create a notification:

```
...
FirebaseMessagingService firebaseMessagingService =
        FirebaseMessagingService.instance;
    String? userFCMToken = await firebaseMessagingService.readToken();

    if (userFCMToken != null) {
      // Calculate notification time for each rental
      for (var rental in rentalListFuture) {
        DateTime rentalNotificationTime =
            rental.fromDate!.subtract(Duration(days: 7));

        // Check if now is between the 7 days before window and the reservation start time
        if (DateTime.now().isAfter(rentalNotificationTime) &&
            DateTime.now().isBefore(rental.fromDate!)) {
          print("sending FCloud Message");
          FirebaseMessagingService().sendFCMNotification(
            userFCMToken,
            'Ride Reminder',
            'Your reserved ride is 7 days away!',
          );
        }
      }
    }
...
```

the error I'm getting:

**Error sending FCM notification: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Object' in type cast**

```
I/flutter (22132): StackTrace: #0      new LinkedHashMap.from.<anonymous closure> (dart:collection/linked_hash_map.dart:187:26)
I/flutter (22132): #1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:633:13)
I/flutter (22132): #2      new LinkedHashMap.from (dart:collection/linked_hash_map.dart:186:11)
I/flutter (22132): #3      platformExceptionToFirebaseException (package:_flutterfire_internals/src/exception.dart:42:9)
I/flutter (22132): #4      convertPlatformExceptionToFirebaseException (package:_flutterfire_internals/src/exception.dart:27:5)
I/flutter (22132): #5      convertPlatformException (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:15:3)
I/flutter (22132): #6      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.sendMessage (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:384:7)
I/flutter (22132): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (22132): #7      FirebaseMessagingService.sendFCMNotification (package:automaat/services/firebase_messaging_service.dart:44:7)
```

I honestly have no clue why it's not working. I've tried ensuring that are my variables are null-safe. If there are any files that I need to upload/show please let me know.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting this error?